# isNumeric('100e00') returns yes while lsisnumeric('100e00') returns no

Tags: coldfusion

I've just seen that `isNumeric('100e00')` returns `yes` while `lsisnumeric('100e00')` returns `no`.

I've checked another hex digits (a,b,c,d) but it returns no with them.

Does anyone know why is it considered `100e00` as a numeric value?

Comment: It's probably a scientific notation thing.  Cast it to an integer, or run a number format on it and see what you get.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`100e00` is scientific notation, ie: 100 * 10^0, or: 100.

```
<cfset string = "100e00">
<cfset numeric = val(string)>
<cfoutput>
values:<br />
string: #string#<br />
numeric: #numeric#<br />
<hr />
isNumeric()<br />
string: #isNumeric(string)#<br />
numeric: #isNumeric(numeric)#<br />
<hr />
lsIsNumeric()<br />
string: #lsIsNumeric(string)#<br />
numeric: #lsIsNumeric(numeric)#<br />
</cfoutput>
```

This outputs:

```
values:
string: 100e00
numeric: 100
isNumeric()
string: YES
numeric: YES
lsIsNumeric()
string: NO
numeric: YES
```

The functionality of [`isNumeric()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fa4.html) and [`lsIsNumeric()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e15.html) differ slightly beyond the locale-awareness of the latter.

isNumeric() states this:
"Determines whether a string *can be converted to a numeric value*"
(my *emphasis*)

lsIsNumeric() states:
"Determines whether a string is a valid representation of a number"

Do you see the subtle difference? the former will try to force the value to be a numeric, whereas the latter just does what it's told: tells you if it's a numeric or not.

Comment: you can use `formatBaseN(100e00,10)` to evaluate that to 100. `formateBaseN(100e5, 10)` would equal 10000000.  Works for strings as well. `formateBaseN('100e5', 10)` still equals 10000000.  Or number format like Dan suggested numberformat('100e5') = 10,000,000

Comment: Or just use `val()`. Which is closer to the intent of what you'd be trying to do in this case.

Comment: nope, val doesn't evaluate the exponent. val('100e5') returns 100, not 10000000. `Converts numeric characters that occur at the beginning of a string to a number.`

Comment: Blimey. That bites. OK, well one can do this then: `<cfoutput>#'100e5'*1#</cfoutput>`. I just don't like leveraging `formatBaseN()` here because you're not really doing a base conversion, you're just leveraging the fact it casts `100e5` to a number before using it. `numberFormat()` is better, I think.

Comment: yep, you can do `#'100e5'+0#` too.  anything that does math on it but doesn't change the value.